# KRDC to Debian machine gives blue screen on reboot

Tags: debian, remote, vnc

I have two Debian machines, using XRDP on one and KRDC on the other to create an RDP connection between the two. This process works fine, until I reboot the server. Then, most often, after the server reboots, KRDC simply displays a blue screen when I try to log in. Sometimes I get the XRDP login screen, and then XRDP freezes during the login sequence. I have to restart the server several times to get the connection working again.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

krdc doesn't reflect errors properly.
In my case I had old password saved in kwallet, so fixed the problem by removing saved server krdc password from kwallet.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem...
I install freerdp and my problem was done..
ref: http://arief-jr.blogspot.ca/2016/01/using-rdp-remote-desktop-protocol-with.html

Luc Brassard

Comment: Please expand your answer to include the necessary information here, without having to go through the link. Otherwise link-rot will make your answer useless over time (if not deleted as a link-only answer before that).